# Show that $f$ is globally analytic.

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is of class ${C}^{\infty}$. Suppose that for every $a, b \in\mathbb{R}\ (a<b)$ there exists $K>0$ (possibly depending on $a$ and $b$) such that $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq K$ for every $x\in [a, b]$ and every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Show that $f$ is globally analytic.

**My attempt:** I tried to use Taylor series, but I got nowhere!

Any comment?

Comment: Use integral form of remainder: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try using the bound to show that the the error term for the Taylor series goes to zero over all intervals.